# How to add 5 pluses to an existing string using String.format?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, string.format

How to add 5 pluses to an existing string using String.format?

I know that this way you can add spaces to an existing line:

```
String str = "Hello";
String padded = String.format("%-10s", str);
```

How to add plus?
I did not find how the plus symbol is indicated.

the result should be:

```
"Hello+++++"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no flag that allows you to pad `+` instead of space. Instead you need to do something like:

```
String.format("%s%s", str, "+".repeat(5))
```

or maybe just:

```
str + ("+".repeat(5))
```

[`String.repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) was introduced in Java 11.

You could also just hardcode it:

```
String.format("%s+++++", str)
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution with "+".repeat(5) is very cool. Is there such a thing for Java 8?

Comment: @KirillSereda Not in Java itself, but you could just Apache commons-lang3 which has [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.repeat(String,int)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.10/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-java.lang.String-int-), or you could write a static helper method yourself. The linked duplicate also provides more alternative solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much! My solution: StringUtils.rightPad(str, 20, "+")

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hello";
String padded = String.format("%s+++++", str);
System.out.println(padded);
```

?
if you want to have it more generic and extract it to the method you can try to do sth like this:

```
String str = "Hello";
int size = 10;
String pluses = "";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) pluses = String.format("%s+", pluses);
String padded = String.format("%s%s", str, pluses);
System.out.println(padded);
```

Comment: Thank you. But if there are 20 pluses? Is there any universal solution to indicate the number of pluses as in the example above with spaces?
e.g. String.format ("% - 10s", str);

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it's ok for you you can vote on +

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hello"

String padded = String.format("%s+++++", str);
// or
String padded = str + "+++++";
```

Comment: Thank you. But if there are 20 pluses? Is there any universal solution to indicate the number of pluses as in the example above with spaces?
e.g. String.format ("% - 10s", str);

Answer (score 1):

String.format("%s%s", str, "++++");

This should work.

Comment: Thank you. But if there are 20 pluses? Is there any universal solution to indicate the number of pluses as in the example above with spaces?
e.g. String.format ("% - 10s", str);